# Screen resolution bigger than 1366 x 768

Tags: screenshot, resolution

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the MSN messenger window for a print, but I need it to be 2693 x 1772 pixels.

What can I do to make the screenshot this big? Or simply: how can I make my screen resolution that way so I can capture the screen shot in a good resolution?

Thanks

Comment: Is that 2693x1772 the resolution of your own screen, or of the desired image? How are you taking the screenshot?

Comment: Why on earth do you need a resolution of 2693X1772 ?!? Almost any good image editing program can create images at any resolution you specify.

Comment: You need it for printing, so I understand the need for quality. However, messenger windows are not scaling up. Even if you could take the screenshot for such resolution, you would end with very small pictures and text areas. The best solution will be to scale it up yourself, and the cost of quality (but not that much).

Comment: If you could get a properly proportioned window that size (about A4/ US-letter paper at 300lpi) it would look wrong. Talk to someone who understands printing, because you don't "need" that resolution, in fact it would be Bad.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the maximum window size is limited to the size of your screen (as you already noticed).

Try to install a virtual PC (with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx)) on your real PC and give it a huge virtual display. Note that you need a second license of Windows for that to be legal.

Alternatively, buy a [graphics card](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/radeon-5870-eyefinity6,2595.html) which can drive four 1920x1080 displays (and four displays).

Answer (score 0):

"whaat can i do to make the screenshot this big?"

Well, this is probably not what you want.
But you could use an image editing or converting tool to get the desired resolution (paint.NET or imagemagick).